# re-initialize an input with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a ajax method that reloads only a div when service response

```
success:  function (response) {

    $( "#list" ).load(window.location.href + " #list" );
    $( "#badge" ).load(window.location.href + " #badge" );
    $('.b-number').niceNumber();
}
```

This niceNumber initialize an input, i downloaded from here
https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Number-Input-Spinner-jQuery-Nice-Number.html
, 
but when I re-load the div #list, the method niceNumber that apply all my .b-number inputs does not work.
Is there a correct way to do this? To re-init the method without reload the entire page?

Comment: hmm you are setting your `.b-number` after ajax request but when you re-load your page do you `re initialize` your b-number again? I think you probably need 2, one on page load and one after ajax request. I need more context about this problem before I can  give you the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.load` is asynchronous so it will not complete by the time you call  niceNumber. You can use its callback function to do this.

```
$( "#list" ).load(window.location.href + " #list", redo);
$( "#badge" ).load(window.location.href + " #badge", redo );
function redo(){
    $('.b-number').niceNumber();
}
```